# XAMPP VS MAMP on Mac

Tags: macos, mac, xampp, mamp

I'm a XAMPP user ever since whether it's in Windows or Mac environment. But recently I saw MAMP from another user, I saw some cool features like you can associate a domain without coding it up.

If you're on a Mac, what are your reasons for using MAMP over XAMPP aside from that MAMP is meant for Mac. Does it have support for other versions of PHP? Did it increase your workflow?